# Recognize that checkbox was unchecked during a php/html form edit

Tags: php, html, checkbox

I'm creating a form using php/html which allows a user to enter data, then review and optionally edit inputs at the end of the process before submitting.  Some of the inputs are done using check boxes. Using stack overflow, a great resource, I found out how to display the previously entered data and allow the user to make changes. My issue is with the checkboxes.  I use the session variable to indicate whether a checkbox had been previously checked. During edit, when the user checks a previously unchecked box, it will update,  but when the user unchecks one that was checked, it remains checked in the Session variable and database.

Here is the code I use to display the previously entered checkboxes on the "update" page:

```
<?php 
session_start();
...
<input type="checkbox" name="Name1" <?php if($_SESSION['Name1']=="on"){echo 'checked';}?>/>
...
```

Then when the user makes their changes, and clicks the UPDATE button the session variables are updated with this code:

```
<?php
session_start();
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) { $_SESSION[$key] = $value;}
```

The text fields update perfectly.  Any help would be appreciated!  I've been spinning my wheels on this one for two days!!!

Here are some additional excerpts of the code:
from php file that displays the fields for update:

```
<form method="post" action="UpdateVolunteerEnter.php">
/* example of text field */
Email Address
<input type="text" name="VolunteerEmail" id="VolunteerEmail" size="50" value="<?php echo $_SESSION['VolunteerEmail']; ?>"/>
<br />
/*example of checkbox field */
<input type="checkbox" name="AfterProm" id="AfterProm" <?php if($_SESSION['AfterProm']=="on"){echo "checked";}?>/>
<br />
<input type="submit" name="Update" id="Update" value="UPDATE" />   
</form>
```

And here is excerpted code from the file that processes the inputs with your suggested updates:

```
<?php
session_start();
//Update Session Variables

foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    if($value == ''){
        unset($_SESSION[$key]);
    }
    else {
        $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

So after doing a little trouble shooting and more digging, I discovered that if a checkbox is unchecked it is not in the $_POST and therefore the $_SESSION Variable was not being updated.  I added the following statement in my php file that processes the form inputs to check for this occurrence and rectify it so that it now works!!!

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {$_SESSION[$key] = $value;}
//Check for unchecked checkboxes (one if statement per checkbox)
if (isset($_SESSION['checkbox1']) AND !isset($_POST['checkbox1'])){unset($_SESSION['checkbox1']);}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check if those checkboxes are not empty like this `$_POST[$key] != ''` and if they are empty unset them from `$_SESSION` array like this `unset($_SESSION[$key])`. 
So the whole code is:

```
session_start();
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) { 
    if($value == ''){
        $_SESSION[$key] = false;
        unset($_SESSION[$key]);
    }
    else {
        $_SESSION[$key] = $value;
    }
}
```

**UPD:** Try to unset the needed variables explicitly. This is not a good example of code, but I don't know the context, so that's all I can advise.

```
if($_POST['Name1'] != 'on'){
    $_SESSION['Name1'] = false;
    unset($_SESSION['Name1']);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response… but it didn't work ;o(  Checkboxes that are unchecked in the edit screen still show up as checked on the review screen after I inserted the suggested code. Any other ideas?

Comment: Thanks for your continued interest!   I've added additional code in my original problem statement.

Comment: Try to set `$_SESSION[$key]` to `false` before `unset` statement. Updated answer.

Comment: so doing a little trouble shooting i've discovered that if the checkboxes are not checked they are not posted and therefore are not being updated, so how do I get them to post?  do I need to set a value?

Comment: Thanks for your help Dima!  I've figured out an answer (see updated question)… not the most glamorous code, but I'm just glad it works